# Find $f'(-5)$ if $f$ is odd, periodic and differentiable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives, trigonometry

Ok so here is the question given to me:
The function $f (x)$ is odd, periodic and differentiable for $x∈ R$.
The period of $f$ is 7 , $f(− 2) = 2$ and $f'(-2)=\frac{1}{3}$.

I have been asked to find $f'(-5)$ for one of the parts of the question.

My take:

From the constraints given to $f$, the only possible option is $sin$ as $tan$ is not differentiable $∈ R$ and $cos$ is even. (I am only looking at the three basic ones, not their inverses)

therefore, from the graph of $sin$, I know that $f'(-2)$ = $f'(-9)$ but how does this help me find $f'(-5)$?

Originally I would have expected the gradient to be the opposite sign because it's roughly halfway through but it appears not to be(from the answers). If you look at the coordinates of $0$ and $\pi$, the gradient is reversed. So could someone help me figure out why? I do not know where I am going wrong.

[image]

Comment: f is odd so
$$f(-x)=-f(x)\implies -f'(-x)=-f(x)$$  or $f'(-x)=-f'(x)$ $$f(x+7)=f(x)\implies f'(x+7)=f'(x)$$ put x=-2 $$f'(5)=f(-2)=f'(-5)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is odd. Therefore you have $f'(-x)=f'(x)$ (do you see that?).

Now by 7-periodicity and the previous property $f'(-5)=f'(2)=f'(-2)$.

Comment: "$f′(−x)=f′(x)$", Is that because the derivative is an even function?

Comment: Yes just take the definition of odd function f(-x)=-f(x).  By differentiating you see that the derivative of an odd function is even.

Comment: @Thomas Why is $f'(-5)=f'(2)$? The function is periodic, but we don't know if it's derivative is periodic.

Comment: Good point. Since f(x+7)=f(x) , by differentiation and rule of composition f'(x+7)=f'(x) so the derivative is periodic as well. But intuitively this should be true if we think how the derivative is defined as a limit of finite differences and translating